# Как слушать порт что бы он был виден лишь одному приложению в локалхосте?

Tags: windows, winapi

Есть сервер написанный не мной, в виде приложения. Нужно его запускать допустим на порту 4444, но так что бы этот порт был доступен лишь моему приложению (оно и запускает сервер), а для остальных он не существовал бы.

Ну и заодно что бы можно было запустить несколько связок "Мое приложение + Сервер", и они бы не конфликтовали.

Comment: Почитайте про docker, герой :)

Comment: @dIm0n Про Docker я знаю, но не вариант, не заставлять же людей его ставить, тем более под Windows 7|8 он может использовать только виртуализацию, что очень медленно.

Comment: ну или HTTPS+SSL с собственными сертификатами.

Answer (score 2):

Запустите сервер на машине чтоб видно было только приложениям на этой машине. Напишите свой сервис прокси, мидлеваре который будет  обрабатывать только ваши запросы и перенаправлять на localhost:4444. Далее Ваш сервис ваши правила.

Comment: Сервер на отдельной машине не вариант.

Comment: Ну не вариант значит не вариант. Ставьте nginx и проксируйте